# thumbnail image path and file path for gallery thumbnail images

Tags: posts, post-thumbnails

what is the thumbnail image path?
When asked for the file path for the gallery thumbnail image, what is needed?
 the terms: thumbnail image path
and
file path
is not familiar to me.

Answer (score 0):

The thumbnail image path is the path to the original image from which the thumbnail was created. If you are in the File Upload screen you should be able to click on the File Links To: File URL, or Gallery Links to Image URL for galleries, which should automatically fill the text area with the correct location.